# Cambiar el nombre de un archivo con Python

Tags: python

Estoy intentando cambiar el nombre de un archivo usando Python pero el nombre no cambia. El programa tiene que tomar una foto, guardarla, copiarla a un servidor, cambiar el nombre de la foto copiada y cambiar el nombre de la foto original. Así que, en primer lugar, defino una variable que va a ser una fecha y hora exactas. Después de eso, tomo una foto y la guardo como imagen.jpg A continuación, copio imagen.jpg a otra ruta (ruta del servidor), y trato de cambiar su nombre usando la variable que definí antes (que es la hors y fecha actual). Pero el nombre no cambia y el archivo se elimina. Después de eso cambio el nombre de la foto original con la misma función y el nombre se cambia .... No sé por qué la foto copiada no cambia su nombre. Aquí está el código:

```
import picamera
import os
import shutil
fecha = time.strftime("%c")  # En esta variable se guarda la fecha actual y la hora para renombrar la foto guardada          
camera.capture('/home/pi/Desktop/RaspAlarm/imagen.jpg')
print("Capturando foto")
time.sleep(5)
print("Copiando foto al servidor")
shutil.copy("/home/pi/Desktop/RaspAlarm/imagen.jpg", "/var/www/html/RaspAlarm/Fotos")
time.sleep(1)
os.listdir("/var/www/html/RaspAlarm/Fotos")
os.rename ("/var/www/html/RaspAlarm/Fotos/imagen.jpg", fecha)
print("Cambiando nombre al archivo")
os.rename ("/home/pi/Desktop/RaspAlarm/imagen.jpg", fecha)
time.sleep(1)
print("Foto guardada")
```

Alguien podria ayudarme? Gracias

Comment: y si haces la captura asi? `camera.capture('/home/pi/Desktop/RaspAlarm/{}.jpg'.format(fecha.replace(' ', '_')))`

Comment: Buenas, no conozco esa estructura. Me puedes explicar como funciona? Muchas gracias!

Comment: Es la linea en la cual haces la captura, lo unico que hice fue cambiar el string, tenia algo llamado 'imagen.jpg', y lo cambié directamente a la fecha, con el método `format` de los strings de python, es decir, para que crear una imagen para luego cambiarle el nombre, mejor es crear la imagen con el nombre cambiado

Comment: De acuerdo. Claro, es mejor así pero yo no conocia el metodo .format y no lo entiendo mucho. Puedes explicarme la sintaxis o funcionamiento del format? Así aprendo algo más, gracias. Por eso lo guardaba con un nombre y luego intentaba cambiar el nombre. Gracias!

Comment: [Aquí](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-string-syntax) está la documentación de `format`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La solución simple es hacer lo que propone @GermanAlzate en su comentario (crear la imágen con el nombre apropiado desde un principio y no renombrar después).

El objeto de la respuesta es explicar porqué `os.rename` funciona con el archivo situado en la ruta de trabajo y no con el que copias en la ruta externa.

Para poder renombrar el archivo es **obligatorio proporcionar la ruta completa tanto en el nombre original como en el de salida o bién estar en el mismo directorio de trabajo que el archivo** renombrado:

```
os.rename("/var/www/html/RaspAlarm/Fotos/imagen.jpg", "/var/www/html/RaspAlarm/Fotos/{}.jpg".format(fecha))
```

Otra opción es cambiar el directorio de trabajo previamente con:

```
os.chdir('/var/www/html/RaspAlarm/Fotos')
os.rename ("imagen.jpg", "{}.jpg".format(fecha))
```

En el caso de la foto original no hay problema porque estas en el mismo directorio de trabajo que el script, de hecho no hace falta proporcionar la ruta completa (al igual que si usas `os.chdir` en el caso anterior):

```
os.rename ("imagen.jpg", '{}.jpg'.format(fecha))
```

El código correcto sería:

```
import picamera
import os
import shutil

fecha = time.strftime("%c")  # En esta variable se guarda la fecha actual y la hora para renombrar la foto guardada          
camera.capture('/home/pi/Desktop/RaspAlarm/imagen.jpg')
print("Capturando foto")
time.sleep(5)
print("Copiando foto al servidor")
shutil.copy("/home/pi/Desktop/RaspAlarm/imagen.jpg", "/var/www/html/RaspAlarm/Fotos")
time.sleep(1)
os.rename ("/var/www/html/RaspAlarm/Fotos/imagen.jpg","var/www/html/RaspAlarm/Fotos/{}.jpg".format(fecha))
print("Cambiando nombre al archivo")
os.rename ("imagen.jpg", "{}.jpg".format(fecha))
time.sleep(1)
print("Foto guardada")
```

Repito que esto es solo por si alguien se encuentra con el mismo problema al usar `os.rename`, lo lógico en tu caso es crear el archivo de primeras usando `fecha` como nombre.

**Edición:**

[str.format()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-string-syntax) funciona mediante "campos de reemplazo" que se denotan con llaves {}. Cualquier cosa que no esté contenida en llaves se considera texto literal, que se copia sin cambios en la salida. Puedes usar el número que quieras de reemplazos en una misma cadena. Puedes pasarle cadenas o variables (incluidos enteros, floats...), operaciones, llamadas a funciones, etc:

```
c = 'mi cumpleaños'
cadena = 'La fecha de {} es el {} de {}.'.format(c, 20+1, 'Enero')
print(cadena)
```

Salida:

> La fecha de mi cumpleaños es el 21 de Enero.

La sustitución se hace según el orden en el que se dan los argumentos, aunque se puede especificar usando indices dentro del `{}`:

```
cadena1 = 'Mi color preferido es el {0}, el tuyo el {1}'.format('azul', 'blanco')
cadena2 = 'Mi color preferido es el {1}, el tuyo el {0}'.format('azul', 'blanco')
print(cadena1)
print(cadena2)
```

Salida:

> Mi color preferido es el azul, el tuyo el blanco
>   Mi color preferido es el blanco, el tuyo el azul

Esto es lo básico, permite más cosas interesantes como alineación de texto, alineación y redondeo de floats, etc. Estas utilidades son de gran ayuda, por ejemplo, para crear salidas tabuladas de datos por pantalla.

**Si usas Python 3.6 o superirores** existe también los llamados [*literales de cadena*](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/) que funcionan de forma parecida pero simplificando aún más siguiendo la filosofía de 'comprensible para humanos' de Python y que permiten hacer 'magia' XD:

```
import datetime
import locale
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_TIME, '')

nombre = 'Andrómeda'
edad = 27
nacimiento = datetime.date(1990, 10, 12)

cadena = f'Mi nombre es {nombre}, mi edad el año que viene es {edad+1} y mi fecha de nacimiento es el{nacimiento: %A %d de %B de %Y}.'
print(cadena)
```

Salida:

> Mi nombre es Andrómeda, mi edad el año que viene es 28 y mi fecha de nacimiento es el viernes 12 de octubre de 1990.

Comment: Buenas, gracias ante todo por la respuesta! He estado usando el os.rename porque no sabia que se podia hacer lo de "{}.jpg".format(fecha)), es más, lo acabo de descubrir que existe. El formato es siempre ese? Lo que hace es sustituir el {} por lo que hay entre los parentesis del format? En ese caso por la variable fecha? Es así su funcionamiento? Gracias nuevamente!

Comment: Tambien decir que usaba la instruccion os.listdir, pensaba que con ello ya te situabas en el directorio. Pero ya veo que para cambiar de directorio hay que usar os.chdir. Para volver al directorio donde está el script nuevamente tendria que volver a usar os.chdir? O vuelve solo? Gracias otra vez @FJSevilla

Comment: @SergioMuñoz no es raro tu error, de hecho hay funciones que trabajan con rutas en `os` que si funcionan con `os.listdir`, realmente lo que hace es retornar una lista con el contenido de la ruta pasada como argumento. En cuanto a lo de `str.format` he editado la respuesta para aclarar su manejo básico. Saludos.

Comment: Fabuloso! Muchas gracias por la explicación, me ha quedado todo clarisimo. Nunca te acostarás sin saber algo más :)

Answer (score 1):

En primer lugar, en ciertos sistemas operativos (léase Windows principalmente) estás creando un nombre de archivo inválido (`fecha`).

```
import time
fecha = time.strftime("%c")
print(fecha)
```

Lo que en definitiva ocurre es que terminás intentando crear un archivo que se llamaría por ejemplo `Mon May  8 16:35:57 2017`, los espacios, letras y números pueden ser válidos, pero los `:` no. Te sugiero que siempres pegues el texto completo del error, sino es más difícil hacer un diagnóstico.

Por empezar armaría mejor el nombre del archivo, algo así:

```
import time
fecha = time.strftime("%Y%m%d-%H%M%S")
print(fecha)
```

Lo cual nos daría un nombre más compatible, por ej: `20170508-165022` y sería lógico hacer como ya te comentaron algo como esto para terminar de construir el filename:

```
os.rename ("imagen.jpg", "{}.jpg".format(fecha))
```

Pero cuidado, tal como lo dijo @FJSevilla, este rename que estás haciendo asume como archivo de origen, uno que se encuentre en el path de ejecución del Script de Python, debieras cambiar el directorio actual al deseado o usar la ruta completa de los archivos.

Comment: Gracias por la ayuda, voy a modificar la variable fecha tal y como me has recomendado. Así aprendo un poco más con estos pequeños consejos. @PatricioMoracho

Comment: En GNU/Linux el carácter  ' : ' está permitido en los nombres de archivos pero tal como dices en Windows y otros SO tenemos un problema con esto, por compatibilidad mejor evitarlo como recomiendas.

Comment: Es cierto @FJSevilla, estaba convencido que  ':' era inválido también en unix. "Downvote" mi respuesta por favor..

Comment: Jajaja, si te digo la verdad al leer tu respuesta fuy a comprobarlo, estaba casi seguro, pero sembraste la duda en mi.... Lo cierto es que suelo evitar esto aunque sean legales siempre que sea posible, luego llegas con tu archivo a Windows y explota todo XD. Incluso los espacios complican la vida al manejar rutas en la terminal. Aunque estén permitidosm, en Windows no lo están, por lo que creo que tu respuesta y la recomendación que das son acertadas en este aspecto, puedes editarla expliando esto si quieres. Saludos.

Comment: Sí, aun así como decis mejor lo edito y me aseguro que sea compatible en otros sistemas

Comment: Editado con la sugerencia de @FJSevilla.